# How to effectively insert XML data to multiple tables along with the relationships in c#.net 4.0?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have an XML file which has few nodes of similar type. Each of those node will have child nodes in them. The requirement is i need to insert the data of the Main nodes to a particular table and each of it's child table data to a particular child table with the foreign key set as the Primary key of the first insertion. The XML looks like the following sample,

```
       <XML>
          <Provider>
              <providerID>1</ProviderID>
              .
              .
              .
              <ContactInfo>
                 <Address>address1</Address>
                 .
                 .
              </ContactInfo>                  
          </Provider>
           <Provider>
              <providerID>2</ProviderID>
              .
              .
              .
              <ContactInfo>
                 <Address>Address2</Address>
                 .
                 .
              </ContactInfo>                 
          </Provider>
```

The exact requirement is i need to insert provider data to Table1 first, then i need to insert the ContactInfo within each provider to Table2 along with PK of Table1 as FK of Table2, ..............

How can implement this efficiently in c#.net avoiding complex looping? Any one please help me on this....

Comment: Seems like the `xml` should have Provider tags instead of Provider1, Provider2, Provider3, ......?

Comment: @RG1-Yes, you are right i've updated the code accordingly. Now please look in to this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @xml xml
Set @xml = 
'<XML>
<Provider>
    <providerID>1</providerID>
    <ContactInfo>
        <Address>address1</Address>
    </ContactInfo>                  
</Provider>

<Provider>
    <providerID>2</providerID>
    <ContactInfo>
        <Address>address2</Address>
    </ContactInfo>                  
</Provider>

</XML>'
```

---

```
Select 
X.T.value('(providerID)[1]', 'int'),
X.T.value('(ContactInfo/Address)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
From @xml.nodes('/XML/Provider') as X(T)
```

---

ok. Now you have got the query to extract the data from xml. Start with Inserting all these records into a temporary table.

Once done, insert into the first table. done? Now insert the join records(join the first table and temporary table to get the Primary key values from the First table).

Finally, insert the second Temporary table into your second table.

Comment: How can i perform an insert to first table using the above sql statement if i need to insert the primary key to the second table as a foreign key reference?

Comment: Thanks it works.. But the main issue with me was passing the xml from ADO.NET to stored procedure. It should be passed as string and the parameter type should be given as SqlDbType.Xml.

Comment: The code is as follows, XmlDocument xmlDocObj = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocObj.Load("path to test.xml");
string xmlString=xmlDocObj.InnerXml;
using(SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using(SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand("sp_InsertXml",connection))
{command.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.Parameters.Add("@XmlString", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = xmlString;
 connection.Open();
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();}